# derive multiple columns from multiple columns with different names in r

Tags: r

Consider that we have the below data and would like to derive variables z1,z2,z3 from
AB * sys, CC * dia and AD * hr.

could you please help me how i can achieve this in R

```
AB <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
CC <- c(2,3,4,5,6,7)
AD <- c(3,4,5,6,7,8)
x4 <- c('A','B','C','D','E','F')
sys <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
dia <- c(2,3,4,5,6,7)
hr <- c(3,4,5,6,7,8)

testa <- data.frame(AB,CC,AD,x4,sys,dia,hr)
```

get the below output

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

Using `mutate()` from the dplyr package, we can create new columns:

```
testa %>% dplyr::mutate(z1 = AB*sys, z2 = CC*dia, z3 = AD*hr)

  AB CC AD x4 sys dia hr z1 z2 z3
1  1  2  3  A   1   2  3  1  4  9
2  2  3  4  B   2   3  4  4  9 16
3  3  4  5  C   3   4  5  9 16 25
4  4  5  6  D   4   5  6 16 25 36
5  5  6  7  E   5   6  7 25 36 49
6  6  7  8  F   6   7  8 36 49 64
```

Comment: Thank you, what if we have many such columns to multiply. Is there a robust alternate approach

Comment: @jkatam This is perhaps the most efficient way to create new columns using pre-existing ones. If you have more columns, you can add them as additional arguments within mutate(). If you want to loop through multiple columns or achieve something else, you could ask a new question describing what you're after.